# Reenabling PWA camera access in iOS

Tags: ios, camera, mobile-safari, progressive-web-apps, ios-permissions

I'm developing a PWA where the user can scan a QR code (I'm using [zxing-js](https://github.com/zxing-js/library)). On iOS In the safari it behaves as expected: If I allow camera access when prompted, it will open camera preview and allow me to scan code. If I deny access, it won't work, and to regain access to camera in the future I would have to switch from 'Deny' to 'Allow' in the 'Camera' entry in the website's settings (From the "double A" icon to the left of the url bar). Does somebody know where I can manage permissions for camera, location, etc, (specially when needing to re-enable one that was previously denied) for a PWA in iOS?

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no way to do what you want for camera access, but I found that after a PWA (installed) asks for push notification permission and granted, you can manage notification permission in Settings, so it's likely that they will do the same thing for camera access in the future.